# Can I limit export options in UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction

I am generating a PDF in an ios App and exporting that via UIDocumentInteractionController. Because this is a medical app, the lawyer's will only let me export the file to iBooks. I'm not finding any means by which to limit export options, but wanted to confirm that there are no other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: If you only want to export to a single specific app, why bother using UIDocumentInteractionController?

Comment: Is there an alternative? I though I HAD to use the UIDocumentInteractionController.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no suggested way to do this. I have used the method below to block a lot of applications, but it is a hack. I will present the method anyway; maybe you can find something better than I did.

We will restrict the apps that can open the file URL using the `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` method below.

```
- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application
{
    // Only allow iBooks to open. 
    // I don't actually know the application string for iBooks, so I made this one up.
    if (![application isEqualToString:@"com.apple.iBooks"]) {
        // Deleting the document will prevent apps from opening the document and will not crash the app.
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:controller.URL error:nil];

        // Show an alert saying that the app is not allowed to open the PDF
        [controller dismissMenuAnimated:YES];
        UIAlertController *alertController = // make a UIAlertController with some message
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

I repeat, this is very hackish and might not be the best way. Also, this only blocks apps that open a new app when shared. If you select the Mail option to share, then a modal `MFMailComposeViewController` will open and this method will not be called. There may be other apps that behave like this.

Do with this what you will. If you find a better solution, please update us!

Answer (score 2):

Use a UIActivityViewController and a UIActivityItemSource. You can eliminate all system services except iBooks, but you can't stop the user from adding activities such as share extensions from other apps. So the content of the activity view is not entirely up to you. But the UIActivityItemSource is told the identifier of the requesting process, so you can give your PDF to iBooks and give `nil` to everyone else.

Comment: I love to see some code for this type of thing or even a link to an example. Before I saw your answer I was just about to give up on this.

Comment: @Suragch https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/3ecfba2ec68673c125aca6e276a44d43a4cee947/bk2ch13p635activityView2/ch26p901activityView/ViewController.swift